# Significance of the matrix $A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Say you have destinations/places, $A,B,C,D$ and $E$ that are points that you can travel to and from. The only ways to travel between this is by the following schematic:

$A \rightarrow B \\ A \rightarrow E \\ B \rightarrow C \\ B \rightarrow D \\ C \rightarrow A \\ D \rightarrow A \\ D \rightarrow E \\ E \rightarrow B \\ E \rightarrow D$

The links are the arrows and the nodes are the destinations. The connection-matrix is created by the rule

$$a_{ij}=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    1&,& \text{if there is a link from $i$ to $j$.} \\
    0&,& \text{else.} \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

In this case, we get the connection matrix

$$A_c=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&1 \\0&0&1&1&0 \\ 1&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&0}.$$

Computing $(A_c)^2$ and $A+(A_c)^2$ I get

$$(A_c)^2=\pmatrix{0&1&1&2&0 \\2&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&0&1 \\ 0&2&0&1&1 \\ 1&0&1&1&1}, \quad A+(A_c)^2=\pmatrix{0&2&1&2&1 \\2&0&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&0&0&1 \\ 1&1&1&2&1 \\ 0&1&0&1&0}.$$

**Questions:** What is the explanation/significance of the elements in $(A_c)^2$ and $A+(A_c)^2$? What do they intuitivley mean in terms of flights between the destinations?

How should I think and what should I do in order to derive/realize the answer to the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square of an adjacency matrix like $A_c$ can be interpreted as the number of paths of length $2$. For example, the $2$ in the $2$nd row and $1$st column shows that there are two paths of length exactly $2$ from $B$ to $A$ ($B \to C \to A$ and $B \to D \to A$). Correspondingly $A_c^2 + A_c$ gives you all the paths of at most length $2$.

Comment: Okay, I understand what the matrices are now, but how would I have figured this out without you telling me? I don't see how this follows from matrix multiplication and addition like this.

Comment: @Parseval I wrote an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2629111/120540) on this a while ago, you might find it helpful (or not!)

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pjs36 - Say I want to go from an arbitrary place to another, what is the maximum number of flights I need to do? How can I manipulate my adjacency matrix such that it tells me this?